# Projective plane which includes the projective line $\mathbb{S}:[ x_1-x_2+x_3=0=x_2-2x_3+x_4$ and the projective point $P=(1:2:0:1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space

Let we have the projective space $\mathbb{P}^3$. We have to calculate **the projective plane which includes** the projective line $\mathbb{S}:[ x_1-x_2+x_3=0=x_2-2x_3+x_4$ and the projective point $P=(1:2:0:1)$.

---

What I have done is:

First of all I have defined $\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{P}(W)$ and I have calculated the subspace $W$ solving the equations: $W=<(1,1,0,-1),(-1,0,1,2)>$

And now, I don't know if what I have done is ok:

I have calculated the plane (which I have called $T$) which includes the subspace $W$ and the point $(1,2,0,1)$ in the vector space; I mean, $T=(1,2,0,1)+<(1,1,0,-1),(-1,0,1,2)>$ and calculating the implicit equations: $T:[x_1-x_2+x_3+1=0, x_2-2x_3+x_4-3=0$

$T=${$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb{R^4}|x_1-x_2+x_3+1=0, x_2-2x_3+x_4-3=0$}

And now, if I'm not wrong, what the exercise asks to us is $\mathbb{S'}=\mathbb{P}(T)$ and I don't know if I'm doing it well but I've put that: 
$\mathbb{S'}=\mathbb{P}(T)=${$(x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4)\in\mathbb{P}^4|x_1-x_2+x_3+1=0, x_2-2x_3+x_4-3=0$}

But I'm pretty sure that's wrong, owing to the fact that the equations of a projective subspace must be homogeneous.

---

**I don't really know what I'm doing wrong and I neither know how to do it in a correct way.**

Comment: If you find two points on the line, you'll have three points, and then you can find the plane containing them all.

Comment: And how can I find two points on the line? @saulspatz

Comment: You say you solved the equations of the line.  You should be able to plug in values and get some points.  I don't see your solution in the question, though.

Comment: What do you mean? For example the points $(1,1,0,-1)$ and $(1,0,-1,-2)$ ??? @saulspatz

Comment: Okay, so now you have $3$ points.

Comment: So now I have to solve $(x,y,z,t)=k_1(1,2,0,1)+k_2(1,1,0,-1)+k_3(1,0,-1,2)$ or what is the same I have to make a determinant and equal to $0$: 1st line=(x,1,1,1); 2nd line=(y,2,1,0); 3rd line=(z,0,0,-1); 4th line=(t,1,-1-2). Am I right @saulspatz I have obtained the equation 3x-2y+z+t=0

Comment: Am I right @saulspatz ???